# Python: Excel files merge with headers names mapping

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to create a simple python code to merge all excel files in the selected folder.

The input files may or may not have the similar headers. Also, this is possible that the headers may be present in the different files with different names.

So, for this purpose we can select a csv file that contains the mapping of header names. So, the program can check the header names from input files and compare it from mapping file. So, if there is any mapped name is there for particular header, the program will include it under the particular header.

The sample of data in mapping csv is as below:

[Mapping Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeNn4.png)

```
Account_Code    Account_Name    Balance
Kontonummer     Name            Saldo
code            User_name       Running_Balance
id                              Bal
Acc_id
```

I have created the code that merges the excel files and trying to add the headers mapping functionality but not able to do so.

This is the code for merging the files.

```
import pandas as pd, glob, os
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
input_files = glob.glob(filedialog.askdirectory(title='Select Input Folder', master=root) + "/*.xlsx")
if not input_files: print("No Excel files found in input folder"), exit(1)
pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file).assign(File=os.path.basename(file)).set_index('File').reset_index() for file in input_files]).to_excel(f"{os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(input_files[0]))}/Merged.xlsx", index=False)
```

I am expecting some assistance from the python developers community to add mapping functionality into this code. That help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What's the mapping? Showing sample data in OP is helpful.

Comment: i have edited the description to add the mapping data sample.


The sample of data in mapping csv is as below:

```
Account_Code  Account_Name Balance
Kontonummer  Name   Saldo
code   User_name  Running_Balance
id        Bal
Acc_id  
```